# Can objects repeat in commutative diagrams?

Tags: reference-request, notation, category-theory, relations, abstract-algebra

Are objects allowed to repeat in commutative diagrams? This seems to be necessary when representing endomorphisms such as the morphism $f : X \to X$ in the category $\mathbf{Set}$, such as when $f$ is a constant function? Or in the category of binary relations, the morphism $R = \{(x, x)\} \subseteq X \times X$?

That is, can commutative diagrams include parts that look like $X \xrightarrow{f} X$ or $X \xrightarrow{R} X$?

The [formal definition of a diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram#Diagrams_as_functors) as a functor from an index category $J$ to a category $C$ seems to allow this if different objects in $J$ are mapped to $X$, but I'd like to confirm if my reasoning is correct.

Comment: Yes; that's the whole point of working with diagrams (aka functors) rather than subcategories (aka functors that are injective on both objects and arrows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course! A functor $J \to C$ need not be injective on objects.

Another example is when you want to take the product of an object with itself.